# How to save dataframe without an index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

liste = pd.read_excel("testListe.xlsx")

#delete the numbering column in dataframe

liste.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

Comment: please tell us more about the structure of the data in the excel file.

Comment: Are you trying to delete the index?

Comment: `liste.to_excel("output.xlsx",index=False)`

Answer (score 5):

It seems like you want to save without `index`:

```
liste.to_excel("output.xlsx", index=False)
```